# How would I return all children related to a property in a generic method using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

Below is a method in my generic repository which every repository inherits from.

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<T> queryable = GetAll();

    if (includeProperties != null)
    {
        queryable = includeProperties.Aggregate(queryable,(current, include) => current.Include(include));
    }

    return queryable;
}
```

Now my homepage class looks something like this:

```
public virtual List<ThumbnailLinks> ThumbnailLinks { get; set; }
public virtual List<ThumbnailImages> ThumbnailImages { get; set; }
public virtual List<BannerImage> BannerImages { get; set; }
public virtual List<Paragraphs> Paragraphs { get; set; }
public virtual List<BackGroundImage> BackGroundImages { get; set; }
public virtual List<Header> Header { get; set; }
```

You can see I have a bunch of lists that all return. But `Header` is different. It has a list of its own and in that list is another list.

So the hierarchy looks something like this:

```
Header -> GroupedItems -> Items
```

My service page has a method called `GetHomePage` which looks like this:

```
public ICollection<HomePage> GetHomePage()
{
    var retVal = _unitOfWork.HomePageRepository
                            .GetAllIncluding(o => o.BannerImages, o => o.Paragraphs, o => o.ThumbnailLinks, o => o.ThumbnailImages, o => o.Header, o => o.BackGroundImages)
                            .ToList();
    return retVal;
}
```

Now `retval` returns everything including `Header`, but none of its children!

My question is: how would I modify or extend my generic method to include children properties, and so on and so on?

For some additional setup, my controller or restful API looks like this:

```
public class HomePageController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHomePageService _homePageService;
    private readonly IErrorService _errorService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public IActionResult GetHomePage()
    {
        ResponseDto<ICollection<HomePageDto>> response = new ResponseDto<ICollection<HomePageDto>>();
           
        response.Data = _mapper.Map<ICollection<HomePageDto>>(_homePageService.GetHomePage());
    }
}
```

Then it calls my service which is posted above. But here is the whole thing

```
public class HomePageService : IHomePageService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public HomePageService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public ICollection<HomePage> GetHomePage()
    {
        var retVal = _unitOfWork.HomePageRepository.GetAllIncluding(o => o.BannerImages, o => o.Paragraphs, o => o.ThumbnailLinks, o => o.ThumbnailImages, o => o.Header, o => o.BackGroundImages).ToList();
        return retVal;
     }
}
```

`UnitOfWork` looks like this:

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
 {
     private readonly DataContext _context;

     public UnitOfWork(DataContext context)
     {
         _context = context;
     } 

     public IHomePageRepository HomePageRepository => new HomeRepository(_context);
}
```

And my home repository looks like this

```
public class HomeRepository : GenericRepository<DataContext,HomePage>, IHomePageRepository
{
    public HomeRepository(DataContext context) : base(context) { }
}
```

And finally this is my generic repository

```
public class GenericRepository<TContext,T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class where TContext : DbContext
{
    protected readonly TContext _context;

    public GenericRepository(TContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> queryable = GetAll();

        if (includeProperties != null)
        {
            queryable = includeProperties.Aggregate(queryable,(current, include) => current.Include(include));
        }

        return queryable;
    }
}
```

Edit:

so based on a few comments I changed my home repository to look like the following.

```
 public class HomeRepository:GenericRepository<DataContext,HomePage>,IHomePageRepository
    {

        private readonly DataContext _context;
        public HomeRepository(DataContext context) : base(context) {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IQueryable<HomePage> GetAll()
        {
            var retVal = _context.HomePages.Include(o => o.Header).ThenInclude(x=>x.Items).ThenInclude(y=>y.Items).Include(o => o.Paragraphs)
                .Include(o => o.BannerImages).Include(o => o.ThumbnailLinks).Include(o => o.BackGroundImages).Include(o => o.ThumbnailImages);
            return retVal;
        }
    }
```

Additionally, should I abandon the generic antipattern? I mean I found the generic antipattern to be less overall typing since I could create a generic type to handle just about anything. So I was hoping I could also include(haha) .thenIncludes as well. I mean if not my edit did the trick but that is going around the antipattern I have. **I guess can I do what I want in the generic pattern I have chosen?**

P.S. I have no issue using the above its more curiosity.

Comment: Just don't use GetAllIncluding, and simply write the query using Include and ThenInclude.  The call to GetAllIncluding is just as verbose and not as readable as a normal query.

Comment: You are going down the rabbit hole that is the Generic Repository anti-pattern with EF. EF already provides a perfectly functional generic repository in the `DbSet`, and a perfectly good Unit of Work in the `DbContext`  Simply use them. If you believe a generic repository like this somehow isolates your code from EF-isms behind an abstraction, it does not. Any clever attempt at passing expressions etc. still must be aware of and conform to EF Linq2SQL rules. You are attempting to re-invent a perfectly good wheel.